# How to partially change the scale of the x-axis using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The context of this is plotting odds ratios with confidence intervals. If I plot them as is, then the odds ratios to the right of x=1 would look wider than those to the left of x=1, but that's not a fair visual comparison. So, I'd like to change the scale in the x-axis, so that, for example, the interval [1,5] will look the same length as the interval [0.1,1]. I am working with ggplot2.

Comment: Could you please share some code and reproducible data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You usually do this by plotting the log odds ratio. Then [1, 5] will look the same as [0.2, 1] (i.e. a 5-fold increase or a 5-fold reduction. Either use `aes(x = log(your_odds_ratio, ....`, or `+ scale_x_log10()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. You should make this an answer, @Axeman